# Whenever I write SOQL code it is giving me yellow highlighted line error

Tags: apex, soql, vs-code

[image]
this is the code

Whenever I write SOQL code it is giving me yellow highlighted line error.

Comment: Did you have SOQL extension in your vscode?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post code or error text exclusively as screenshots - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. (Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy your code and put it in a sandbox or code editor.) Instead, copy your code and paste it in the SFSE editor with three backticks (```) above and below it in order to format it as a code block. Similarly, format error text with a greater than symbol (>) at the beginning to format it as a quote block.

Answer (score 3):

It is just an Apex PMD extension. Yellow is not an error, it's a warning. When you hover over it you will see more details (screenshot below).

Apex always works in System Mode. It means that all SOQL or DMLs (insert, update, delete) are executed and user permissions (on profile or permission set) are **NOT** checked.
You see this warning because you should add CRUD validation before SOQL and DML. However it's depends on the project. It's good practice, but not a common one. Leave it as it is if this is not a standard on your project.

[image]